# Postgresql insert into name and value using a variable

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have 2 variables

```
var anycolumn = 'fruit';
var anyvalue = 'apple';
```

I was able to insert the value using variable 'anyvalue' like...

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (fruit) VALUES ($1)", [anyvalue], function(err, result){}
```

Now how do I insert the column name using variable 'anycolumn'?

I'm using node server

```
"INSERT INTO mytable (anycolumn) VALUES ($1)", [anyvalue], function(err, result){}
```

Comment: and this is relate to javascript how? i just see sql here.

Comment: Column names are identifiers, not values, so placeholders don't work for them. Identifiers are like your `var anycolumn` but `'fruit'` would be a value so, you can't use JavaScript variables by name without `eval`, similar things apply in SQL. The usual approach would be to use string concatenation for the column name, there should be a special purpose identifier quoting function in the database driver that you'd use to quote the `anycolumn` before stuffing it into the string.

Comment: [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) does it properly, via support of [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names).

Answer (score 1):

The following example is based on [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
db.none('INSERT INTO mytable($1~) VALUES($2)', [anycolumn, anyvalue])
    .then(()=> {
        // success;
    })
    .catch(error=> {
        // error;
    });
```

Using the same [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) syntax you can inject the table name as well.